# Finch post endpoint definiton Break on finangle 0.14.0.

Tags: endpoint, finch

I tried to define a finch post endpoint, for simplify purpose, I used stringBody, 
The endpoint definition looks like:

val e = "product"::"v1"::"createBody"::stringBody

And when I tried to start the service, got following question:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsStatsReceiver.com$twitter$finagle$stats$StatsReceiverWithCumulativeGauges$setter$com$twitter$finagle$stats$StatsReceiverWithCumulativeGauges$$gaugeFn_$eq(Ljava/util/function/Function;)V
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.StatsReceiverWithCumulativeGauges$class.$init$(CumulativeGauge.scala:133)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsStatsReceiver.(MetricsStatsReceiver.scala:175)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsStatsReceiver.(MetricsStatsReceiver.scala:179)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsStatsReceiver.(MetricsStatsReceiver.scala:180)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsStatsReceiver.(MetricsStatsReceiver.scala:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.twitter.app.LoadService$$anonfun$5.apply(LoadService.scala:74)
at com.twitter.app.LoadService$$anonfun$5.apply(LoadService.scala:63)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at com.twitter.app.LoadService$.apply(LoadService.scala:63)
at com.twitter.finagle.util.LoadService$.apply(LoadService.scala:14)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.LoadedStatsReceiver$.(LoadedStatsReceiver.scala:18)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.LoadedStatsReceiver$.(LoadedStatsReceiver.scala)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.FinagleStatsReceiver$.(LoadedStatsReceiver.scala:37)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.FinagleStatsReceiver$.(LoadedStatsReceiver.scala)
at com.twitter.finagle.util.HashedWheelTimer$.(HashedWheelTimer.scala:158)
at com.twitter.finagle.util.HashedWheelTimer$.(HashedWheelTimer.scala)
at com.twitter.finagle.util.DefaultTimer$.(HashedWheelTimer.scala:170)
at com.twitter.finagle.util.DefaultTimer$.(HashedWheelTimer.scala)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.JsonExporter.(JsonExporter.scala:65)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsExporter.(MetricsStatsReceiver.scala:334)
at com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsExporter.(MetricsStatsReceiver.scala:338)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.twitter.app.LoadService$$anonfun$5.apply(LoadService.scala:74)
at com.twitter.app.LoadService$$anonfun$5.apply(LoadService.scala:63)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at com.twitter.app.LoadService$.apply(LoadService.scala:63)
at com.twitter.finagle.util.LoadService$.apply(LoadService.scala:14)
at com.twitter.finagle.http.HttpMuxer$.(HttpMuxer.scala:122)
at com.twitter.finagle.http.HttpMuxer$.(HttpMuxer.scala)
at com.twitter.server.Lifecycle$class.$init$(Lifecycle.scala:12)
at com.shichen.trail.finch.HelloFinch$.(HelloFinch.scala:22)
at com.shichen.trail.finch.HelloFinch$.(HelloFinch.scala)
at com.shichen.trail.finch.HelloFinch.main(HelloFinch.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

What did I miss here?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it is some version nightmare. This project is using scala 2.10 for now due to a lot of downstream dependencies. And I believe finch-core for 2.10 version is very primative. I'm now trying to upgrade the project to scala 2.11 and see what happens. I have a test project that use 2.11 and handle the post request just fine.

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard binary incompatibility problem. Try removing all the explicit finagle dependencies (including util) and let Finch bring the version of Finagle it needs to. Also make sure TwitterServer (if you're using it) is aligned with that version.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. That seems solve the problem. Removing as much as possible the unnecessary references and imports made me moving forward a lot.